# MVC Create method data flow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dataflow

I think i know some of the basics of MVC but there's one thing which I don't understand yet.

In the view Create which is generated automatically when you set up your project, how is data sent to the controller? I'm used to seeing ActionLinks with parameters but here there's no actionLink so I can't understand how data travel from the view to the controller.

Could you explain it to me please?

Comment: do you mean by the view Create after you scaffold it?

Comment: That's it. I've found a post which explains it very well. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part6

Answer (score 1):

as you know, in your view, the very first line (usually) tells the view, about the *Model* being used within this view. like:

```
@model Models.CarViewModel
```

lets suppose, you have a form on this view, and it is posted to some action called *Edit*. Then you must have your *Edit* action, expecting the parameter of type you used as model in your view. like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult(CarViewModel model)
{
    //logic
}
```

This convention is known as [Strongly Typed View](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views). Suppose Then you have some textbox for a property *Name* of your model as:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)
```

when the form is posted to *Edit* Action, the variable *model* in parameter of *Edit* action will be holding the respective values. *i.e, model.Name*